# Storing and updating API Data in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

I am working on a web app where I have made a call to an API and stored the data using MongoDB. This data gets updated daily so I will need to be able to update the data daily by clicking a button in admin site. What is the best way to approach this?

I am new to using databases so I do not know the best approach. The reason I am wanting to store data in database is so I can store it using Redux or Context API so when someone goes to a page the data will be available faster instead of having to make a new API call (and wasting an API call)  every time someone visits a page.

My database contains about 630 documents at a time.

Issue:

I need to update the 630 documents in my database to match the 630 documents coming from API that changes daily so I need to figure out what to query MongoDB to accomplish this.

Comment: This question is very generic. Add the relevant code/data to your question and indicate at which specific point you have a problem.

Comment: I added more details to question. The issue is I do not know how to query the collection to update all documents at one time in the most efficient way to match the incoming data from API.

Comment: Question not clear, please provide additional details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a way to solve my issue.

Previously I have updated a document one at a time so I used something along the lines of `db.collection.update(<query>,<update>)` to update one document. Issue I was facing was I needed to update all the documents in collection at one time. So by using `db.collection.remove({})` I was able to remove all the documents in collection then used `db.collection.create(myData)` to add new updated data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule).

It's very much like cron-job. But runs on the node application. Make sure the scheduler runs every 24 hours interval and put this database oprtation there.

> Note that Node Schedule is designed for in-process scheduling, i.e.
>   scheduled jobs will only fire as long as your script is running, and
>   the schedule will disappear when execution completes. If you need to
>   schedule jobs that will persist even when your script isn't running,
>   consider using actual cron.